# about the direct intervention of a child's gender

Tags: chromosome

Can we determine the gender of a child now,I mean,not randomly?
There are equal amount of sperms with X chromosome and Y chromosome.
Can these two kinds of sperms be distinguished easily?
If yes,we can choose the kind of sperm to meet the ovum,then the gender of the child can be determined.

Answer (score 3):

Sperms can and are sorted using [flow cytometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_sorting) to attempt to separate sub-populations carrying X or Y chromosomes. The technique isn't perfect but it is undergoing "clinical trials" in the USA.

Comment: Gender selection as an invitro fertilization method has been in limited use in the US for decades. i just found this link: http://chooseagender.com/Methods-Of-Gender-Selection.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"Sex" is the right word when talking about biology.  "Gender" is about the cultural signifiers and differences that a culture puts on people depending on their sex.

There are transexual people and transgender people and intersexed people...so it's a little rude to them to act like biological sex is a binary thing, or that is it totally the same as gender.

Comment: yes, `sex selection` also helps. It is illegal in China and India,but not in most of the countries especially in western countries. It should be a basic human right for parents?